# Enumerate nested object faster

Tags: c#

I have a question, if there is a possibility to enumarate my nested object in a "more beautiful" way:

```
foreach (EntityOpportunity opt in entAccount.Opportunities)
{
    foreach (EntityActivityPointer activity in opt.Activities)
    {
        condRegardingObjectId.Values.Add(activity.Id);
    }
}
```

There is a list of activities in each opportunity entity and I need just the Id.

Best regards

Comment: "and I need just the If of them" - should that say Id ?

Comment: Is the question performance related or beautification related?

Comment: I suppose you could apply higher order functions but this seems to be idiomatic C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you have. Sure, there are things like `SelectMany` / `Select` that could put it onto fewer lines, but that has overheads (delegate creation, and not being able to use custom iterators - where-as `foreach` *can* use custom iterators, and all the IL is in one place).

Frankly, the only change I would make is to grab the target first:

```
var list = condRegardingObjectId.Values;
foreach(EntityOpportunity opt in entAccount.Opportunities) {
    foreach(EntityActivityPointer activity in opt.Activities) {
        list.Add(activity.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `var` and shorten `activity` to `act`. Personally I would think it looks nicer but not much else.

Comment: @ChaosPandion well, you're *probably* right; however, without knowing the declared typed of `Opportunities` and `Activities`, we can't say that for sure - but: I suspect it would be fine here ;p

Comment: You're right. That issue tends to always creep up on me. The non-generic collections of System.Text.RegularExpressions are a prime example.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
var IDs = entAccount.Opportunities
                    .SelectMany(opt => opt.Activities, (opt, act) => act.Id);
```

Since you don't specify what `condRegardingObjectId` is, I would be guessing to know how to import the collection of values as a whole (something like `AddRange`)?

Comment: Oh, +1, didn't ever notice that overload !

Comment: Would probably need some `condRegardingObjectId.Values.AddRange(IDs);` too

Comment: @MarcGravell - correct - not sure what type `condRegardingObjectId` is and don't want to wager a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq if you only want the Ids of the Activities:

```
var activityIds = entAccount.Opportunities.SelectMany(p=>p.Activities).Select(p=>p.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

for List T object :

```
entAccount.Opportunities.ForEach(opt => opt.Activities.ForEach(activitiy => condRegardingObjectId.Values.Add(activity.Id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess looking at your objects:

```
                    foreach (EntityActivityPointer activity in entAccount.Opportunities.SelectMany(opt => opt.Activities))
                    {
                        condRegardingObjectId.Values.Add(activity.Id);
                    }
```